# How to filter files in folder references with XCode 4

Tags: xcode, filtering, packaging

I want to include a folder in my XCode project. I have to add it as a "folder reference" because I want to keep its structure.
But this folders include xml files which I need, and .txt files which I don't want to include in my project.
Is it possible to filter those files with xCode ?